# Android Java Update Refresh Gui

Tags: java, android, user-interface, refresh

How do I update / refresh the gui in an application lets say for every second.
I want to built a timer which count down from one date to anther, but the main question is how to refresh a gui every second.

Comment: what do you want to refresh, what items?

Comment: basically a textview which show the minutes left to lets say 12pm

Comment: The [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) method will force a view to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CountDownTimer` [Link to docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, basicaly, you need to use this tutorial. Now, when using timer you can say for every n + 1 seconds `TextView.setText(String.valueOf(s));`

Refer to the tutorial:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/